# How to style/detect highlighted boxes generated from browser native search in page

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way to style the yellow (or whatever color) highlight boxes that show up when you use the browser's native find-in-page function? If so, how?

Additionally, is there any way to detect which elements are highlighted (or even the fact that there are elements highlighted) with JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firefox**

- From a website: no, there is no way.
- An add-on or user (via about:config) may modify the `ui.textHighlightForeground` and `ui.textHighlightBackground` preferences.

For the curious: [Responsible code](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/generic/nsTextFrame.cpp#3328).

**Chrome**
(and likely other webkit/blink browsers)

Nope. [Colors are hardcoded](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/rendering/InlineTextBox.cpp&q=platformActiveTextSearchHighlightColor&sq=package%3achromium&type=cs&l=1296).

No idea about IE and other browsers (well, there aren't many left).